# Copy/Paste in Gimp not working properly

Tags: gimp, copy-and-paste

I am using Gimp to create a skin for a 3D model of a building.  I am currently placing different styles of windows in my model.  To do this, I am opening a window file, copy the image and paste it into the master image as a new layer so that I can move and scale it properly.

The first image I copied worked properly.  When I moved to the second image, I copied it, but when I pasted it as a new layer, it pasted the first image instead.  I used undo to remove it, copied the image again and when I pasted it, it was the proper image.  Every other image I've done has done the exact same thing (the third image pasted as the second, fourth as third, etc).  This is becoming a huge time waster and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug that I've run into?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, I can't replicate the problem. Copy and paste seems to be working fine in GIMP. I am going to vote to close this as off-topic because it's almost impossible to answer without access to specific files, or access to your computer system. Also tech support is off topic here. If you still have issues, then you could [report it as a bug](https://www.gimp.org/bugs/) to the GIMP developers.

Comment: This happens to me every time now. I copy a bitmap to the Windows clipboard, and can see that the copy operation is successful. For instance, I can paste the image in Microsoft Paint. But if I paste in GIMP, I instead get a previously pasted image. The only way to paste the current clipboard image is to restart GIMP.

Comment: I should note that I try to paste *screenshots* that are not saved to file. So I have to paste in Microsoft Paint, save to file, open the file in GIMP, and then remove the file to obtain the desired final state without having to restart GIMP (which takes ages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reproduce. You may have some other application interfering (clipboard manager, security software...)

But there are easier/faster ways to insert images in your current project that don't involve the clipboard. You can either:

- Drag/drop the image file from your explorer to the canvas of the image you are working on
- Drag/drop the image file from your explorer to the Layers list of the image you are working on
- Use `File>Open as layers`. You can even use this to load all your windows images in one go as individual layers, by selecting multiple files in the file selector
- Use `File>Open` to open the file in a new image, and drag the layer from the Layers list to the building image